# Stop DHCP from flooding network with available IP-addresses

Tags: debian, dhcp

I'm currently setting up a dhcp within a network with multiple other DHCP-servers (school) and lately I've received some complaints that my DHCP in particular keep flooding the network and spamming clients with requests.

Is there a simple way to disable the flooding (make it only reservation-based or so)? This is my current setup (`dhcpd.conf`):

```
....
subnet 10.0.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.6.255;
option 10.0.6.1;
}
```

Followed by multiple reservations.

What is wrong? I made some changes in the network/interfaces-file, is it possible thats the reason?

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.6.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.6.0
broadcast 10.0.6.255
```

Comment: What are they referring to as "requests". Which packet is it sending over and over again? [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Operation) is a list. Also how are you interfering with the other DHCP servers? If they're on other subnets then your DHCP traffic isn't going to get routed over to them and if you have multiple DHCP servers on the same subnet then _that_ is the actual problem.

Comment: Actually there is only one other group that keeps getting requests from my DHCP (one VM, within a network that contains at least 120 others). This is what shows in messages when i filter for dhcpd:
...date... dhcp dhcpd: DHCPINFORM from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(public address) via eth1: unknown subnet for client address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (same public IP)  
Followed by:
...date... dhcp dhcpd: DHCPDREQUEST for 192.168.1.144 (not my DHCP or subnet) from ...MAC-address... via eth1: wrong network

Comment: You are not permitted to run multiple independent DHCP servers on a network; the protocol doesn't allow for it. If you're running one on "someone else's" network it's no wonder that you're getting complaints. Disable your DHCP server.